# Glassfish 2.1.1 caches my application web.xml file

Tags: java, glassfish

I have a Struts2 web app deployed on a Glassfish 2.1.1 server, using a web.xml deployment descriptor.

In there, I pass some application params like for example:

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>/media/data/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When I change this param after I have deployed the application on Glassfish, nothing happens, even after a reboot of the whole Glassfish domain.

I have observed that there is a copy of the web.xml file and other files like Hibernate mappings under the "generated" folder under the domain, but can't find a way to affect the value of the param, even if I delete those files.

Is there a way to clear this cache / force regeneration / make Glassfish read again the contents of my changed web.xml file without redeploying the App?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web.xml file is a deployment descriptor.  It is processed when you deploy your app and the resulting deployment configuration is saved in the generated directory for the domain.

If you change the values in the 'source' web.xml, those changes will not propagate into active use until you redeploy your app.

If you want to avoid steps like creating an archive and exploding the archive, I would recommend using [directory deployment](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/820-4332/deploydir-1/index.html)...

You may be able to avoid doing a redeploy if you edit the file in the generated directory and restart the server, but that seems like it will take more time than a directory deployment.  You should also note that this will not work for descriptor elements that are used to generate code at deployment time...